# Array index is always 0, can't get it to iterate through the array in a forloop. Using in MapView

Tags: iphone, arrays, android-mapview

I have an array that I want to show on a mapvew, the forloop iterates fine but the index of thew array is always 0.

```
   self.clientTable = [ClientDatabase database].clientTable;
    ClientTable *info = nil;
    [_nameLabel setText:info.name];
    [_stateLabel setText:info.state];

    int countArray = [self.clientTable count];

    for (int i=0;i<countArray;i++) {

        info.uniqueId=i;
        NSLog(@" i = %d ; id = %d",i, info.uniqueId);

    }
```

however the results are always

24

i = 0 ; id = 0

i = 1 ; id = 0

i = 2 ; id = 0

i = 3 ; id = 0

i = 4 ; id = 0

i = 5 ; id = 0

I know the array has data as it displays in the tableview fine.

Any ideas?

The reason for the above is displaying each item in a mapview.

Thankyou!

Comment: As far as I can see your "info" (ClientTable) is always nil. It is not initialized anywhere. But then again I don't really see the sense in the whole block of code?

Answer (score 2):

Before this line

```
info.uniqueId=i;
```

are you missing something like

```
info = [self.clientTable objectAtIndex:i]
```

?? In the code you've provided you set `info` to `nil`, but never to anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Because you set `info` to `nil`, right up there.